# An interesting answer to my question disappeared. Can I read it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I received an intersting answer to my question [A pipeline of maps/folds where each "transformation layer" is run in parallel in Haskell? ("Vertical" parallelism as opposed to "horizontal" parMap.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30044485/94687), which I wanted to study (despite that it used higher-level libraries as compared to my demand for the understanding of the primitive operations in the original question). It would still greatly help me understand this topic.

But now it disappeared. There are no answers.

Is there a way in such situations to read the disappeared answers to my questions?

Comment: Earn another 7,989 rep and you'll be able to see it.

Comment: Or someone with 10k could screenshot and share it :)

Comment: If you'd accepted the answer answerer could no longer delete it... At very least comment that says that you are looking into the answer would indicate that you care...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the original answer from [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183792/michael).

---

If I understand your question, it is the topic of [the section on 'Pipeline Parallelism'](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch04.html#sec_par-monad-shortest-paths) in the Parallel and Concurrent Haskell book. See the corresponding 
[rsa encryption module](https://github.com/simonmar/parconc-examples/blob/master/rsa-pipeline.hs) in the code respository for the book   (Note the other rsa implementions in the directory.) Here is a version which includes the little Stream library it presupposes for simplicity: http://lpaste.net/132048

Instead of using regular lists, it uses a sort of "ListT done right", so the basic types are:

```
 data IList a = Nil | Cons a (IVar (IList a))
 type Stream a = IVar (IList a)
```

which is basically `ListT IVar a` in the sense of the standard implementations, e.g. in [`pipes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/src/Pipes.html#ListT) or [`list-t`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-0.4.5.1/docs/src/ListT.html#ListT) and many others. (IVar isn't a functor, much less a monad, so the case is a little unusual.) The module goes on to define `fromList`, `map` and `fold` functions, just as you were imagining. The main pipelining operation does a roundtrip of encryption and decryption:

```
pipeline :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> ByteString -> ByteString
pipeline n e d b = runPar $ do
    s0 <- streamFromList (chunk (size n) b)
    s1 <- streamMap (B.pack . show . power e n . code) s0       -- encrypt
    s2 <- streamMap (B.pack . decode . power d n . integer) s1  -- decrypt
    xs <- streamFold (\x y -> (y : x)) [] s2
    return (B.unlines (reverse xs))
```

Here in place of your `xs` we use `streamFromList xs`; the first use of streamMap is like your `map f xs` and the next is like your `map g ys` So `s0` `s1` & `s2` are like your `xs` `ys` & `zs`.

These ideas are implemented in the `monad-par` library, but not exposed: https://github.com/simonmar/monad-par/blob/master/monad-par/monad-par.cabal#L156

Comment: Did you ask @Michael why they deleted it? I would be irritated if I had a good reason to delete my answer and somebody hoisted it. (What if it's wrong or something like that?)

Comment: Better question, it had 2 votes, why was he even *allowed* to delete it? Upvoted answers aren't supposed to be self-deletable...

Comment: The answer author can delete their answer regardless of upvotes, as long as it's not the accepted answer.  The [Disciplined badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) (*Delete own post with score of 3 or higher*) has been awarded thousands of times.